# Spring Boot JPA 2.0.4 Auditing broken?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I upgraded my app from Boot 2.0.3 to 2.0.4 and now `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` from JPA Data Auditing are null rather than containing dates.

DB config contains `@EnableJpaAuditing` and the model contains

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
...
@CreatedDate
private Date createdAt;
@LastModifiedDate
private Date updatedAt;
```

Worked as expected prior to the upgrade.

Any ideas?

Comment: If this worked in Spring Boot 2.0.3 and fails in 2.0.4 without any other changes, then it is a regression. Please file an issue against Spring Data JPA (https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJPA), ideally including a tiny project reproducing the issue.

Comment: Will do. Thanks @JensSchauder